# Externalize the init Logic into External Files

Tags: grails

I want to break-up the BootStrap init content into separate files. My goal is to improve a fairly large BootStrap.groovy file by breaking it up into smaller, intelligently name chunks.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BootStrap` supports autowiring so you could put the logic into service methods, inject the service(s) into `BootStrap` and call the methods from the `init` block.

Alternatively you can have several different files whose name ends in `BootStrap.groovy`, e.g. `SecurityBootStrap.groovy`, `DatabaseBootStrap.groovy`, etc. and they will all be executed.  However I'm not sure if you can guarantee what order the multiple bootstrap scripts will be run, so if ordering is important then the service injection route is safer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it go. You think I'd find something documented if I google?

Comment: @JohnGiotta The dependency injection works exactly equals as a controller.